# Libtool not installing sub-projects

Tags: c++, makefile, installation, autotools, libtool

I'm working on a project in C++ where I'd wish to implement the ability to add plugins. The compilation process is handled by Autotools. I've managed to set the file structure correct, and both the main project and the plugins are compiled, but for some reason the plugins are omitted when running `make install`. When compiling and installing the plugins separately it works fine. Am I missing something here, or why are the plugins not installed from the top folder?

**configure.ac**

```
AC_PREREQ(2.58)
AC_INIT([Net Responsibility],[3.1r323],[contact@netresponsibility.com])
AC_SUBST([LIBTOOL_DEPS])
AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR([.])
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([src/main.cpp])
AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS([plugins/defaultReport])
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([scripts/m4])
AC_CANONICAL_SYSTEM
AC_LANG([C++])
AC_PREFIX_PROGRAM([make])

AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([subdir-objects])

LT_PREREQ([2.2])
LT_INIT([shared])


# Checks for programs.
AC_PROG_CXX
AC_PROG_INSTALL

# Checks for header files.
AC_HEADER_STDC


...

AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

**Makefile.am**

```
# Main library
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libNetResponsibility.la
libNetResponsibility_la_SOURCES = \
      @top_srcdir@/src/MainApplication.cpp\
      ...
libNetResponsibility_la_CPPFLAGS = $(cppFlags)
libNetResponsibility_la_LDFLAGS = -no-undefined $(ldFlags)

# Minimal executable
bin_PROGRAMS = net-responsibility
net_responsibility_SOURCES = @top_srcdir@/src/main.cpp
net_responsibility_LDADD = -lNetResponsibility

dist_pkgdata_DATA = \
      $(top_srcdir)/data/txt.xml\
      $(top_srcdir)/COPYING

dist_pkgdata_SCRIPTS = $(top_srcdir)/scripts/init.d
dist_noinst_SCRIPTS = $(top_srcdir)/scripts/postinst\
      $(top_srcdir)/scripts/prerm

AM_LDFLAGS = -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I scripts/m4

incDirs = -I$(top_srcdir)/include

ldFlags = -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib

cppFlags = $(incDirs)\
           -DPKGDATADIR='$(pkgdatadir)'\
           -DPKGLIBDIR='$(pkglibdir)'\
           -DDATABASEDIR='$(databasedir)'\
           -DPIDDIR='$(piddir)'\
           @CPPFLAGS@

AM_CXXFLAGS = $(incDirs) @CXXFLAGS@
AM_CPPFLAGS = $(cppFlags)

EXTRA_DIST = $(top_srcdir)/lib $(top_srcdir)/include

SUBDIRS = . plugins/defaultReport

install: install-am postinst

uninstall: prerm uninstall-am postrm

postinst:
    $(top_srcdir)/scripts/postinst $(pkgdatadir) $(initdir)

prerm:
    $(top_srcdir)/scripts/prerm $(pkgdatadir) $(initdir)

postrm:
    rm -f $(piddir)/net-responsibility.pid
    rm -f $(pkgdatadir)/blacklist.xml
    rm -f $(pkgdatadir)/config.xml
    rm -rf $(pkgdatadir)/reports
    rm -f $(databasedir)/net-responsibility.db
    rm -f $(initdir)/net-responsibility

.PHONY: prerm postinst postrm
```

**plugins/defaultReport/configure.ac**

```
AC_PREREQ(2.58)
AC_INIT([Net Responsibility Plugin: Default Report],[0.1],[contact@netresponsibility.com])
AC_SUBST([LIBTOOL_DEPS])
AC_SUBST([nrlibdir], ["${libdir}/net-responsibility"])
AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR([.])
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([src/Report.cpp])
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])
AC_LANG([C++])
AC_PREFIX_PROGRAM([make])

AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([subdir-objects])

LT_PREREQ([2.2])
LT_INIT([shared])

# Checks for programs.
AC_PROG_CXX
AC_PROG_INSTALL

AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

**plugins/defaultReport/Makefile.am**

```
# General settings
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I m4

ldFlags = -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib

AM_CXXFLAGS = @CXXFLAGS@

# Module specific settings
nrlib_LTLIBRARIES = defaultReport.la
defaultReport_la_SOURCES = \
   src/Report.cpp
defaultReport_la_LDFLAGS = -module -no-undefined $(ldFlags)
defaultReport_la_LIBADD = -lNetResponsibility
defaultReport_la_CPPFLAGS = -I../../include @CPPFLAGS@
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup `nrlibdir` a little differently:

**plugins/defaultReport/configure.ac**

Remove this line:

```
AC_SUBST([nrlibdir], ["${libdir}/net-responsibility"])
```

**plugins/defaultReport/Makefile.am**

Add this line before `nrlib_LTLIBRARIES`:

```
nrlibdir=$(libdir)/net-responsibility
```

This should help `automake` get `make install` right.

EDIT: I actually tried it this time.  In addition to the above changes, remove the
`install` and `uninstall` targets in `Makefile.am`.  You should be attaching the `postinst`, `prerm` and `postrm` targets to some other install hooks, perhaps something like:

```
install-data-hook:
        $(top_srcdir)/scripts/postinst $(pkgdatadir) $(initdir)

uninstall-local:
        $(top_srcdir)/scripts/prerm $(pkgdatadir) $(initdir)

uninstall-hook:
        rm -f $(piddir)/net-responsibility.pid
        rm -f $(pkgdatadir)/blacklist.xml
        rm -f $(pkgdatadir)/config.xml
        rm -rf $(pkgdatadir)/reports
        rm -f $(databasedir)/net-responsibility.db
        rm -f $(initdir)/net-responsibility
```

Would work instead of those targets.

Comment: thanks for your input! I removed the AC_SUBST macro, and assigned nrlibdir in Makefile.am. `autoreconf` complained about the variable not set (within the scope). When assigning it in plugins/defaultReport/Makefile.am it worked pretty much like before. The plugins are compiled as expected, but they just won't install.

Comment: Thanks a ton! Now it's working like a charm. The problem was the overridden `install` and `uninstall` targets. However it seems to me like the AC_SUBST macro is unrelated, since it works either way.

Comment: I'm not sure that AC_SUBST would always work that way, especially all the way back to autoconf 2.58 and whatever corresponding automake might be installed. I haven't tried setting up an install directory that way before.